# How to convert Speech to Text

Tags: android

Using `SpeechRecognizer` class of Android.

```
private void initRecord() {
    mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,
            Locale.getDefault());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code for converting Speech to Text. its the working code.just Copy and paste Below code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    recordImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button);
    checkPermission();
    initRecord();
    recordImg.setOnTouchListener(this);

}

private void initRecord() {
    mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,
            Locale.getDefault());
    mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float v) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] bytes) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
            //getting all the matches
            ArrayList<String> matches = bundle
                    .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

            //displaying the first match
            if (matches != null)
                editText.setText(matches.get(0));
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }
    });
}
private void checkPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //when the user removed the fingure...
            mSpeechRecognizer.stopListening();
            editText.setHint("You will see input here");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
            editText.setText("");
            editText.setHint("You will see input here");
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```